# Starting client-side validation when using BeginForm helper

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am working on a asp.net mvc 3 application and I have problem with getting my unobtrusive JS validation to work. I've asked very similar question but since I don't get any answers but think that I managed to define my problem better I write this question now.

Searching for an answer for how to get the client-side validation working I saw that there must be some code attached to the click event of the submit button which will start the validation process. I'm not 100% sure that this is so, and this is in fact my problem, but if I'm correct could you help me with the JS I need to add so the validation process can be triggered.

This is my form :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("RecieveDataFromDocument", "Forms", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <table border="1">
        <colgroup>
            <col span="1" style="width: 10%;" />
            <col span="1" style="width: 40%;" />
            <col span="1" style="width: 25%;" />
            <col span="1" style="width: 25%;" />
        </colgroup>
        @Html.Partial("_PartialHeader", Model)
        @Html.Partial("_PartialDrawing", Model)
        @Html.Partial("_PartialBody", Model)
        @Html.Partial("_PartialFooter", Model)
    </table>
    if (ViewBag.Status == 1)
    {
        <button type="submit" id="submitDocument">Save</button>   
    }
    else
    { 
        @Html.ActionLink("Back", "Index")
    }
}
```

and at the bottom of the same view I have this JS :

```
<div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#submitDocument').click(function () {
            window.alert('Hi');
            var test = ($("form").valid());
            window.alert('bye');
        })
    });
</script>
</div>
```

From what I've tested till now I can see the `Hi` message but even if I comment it I never get the `bye`. So any help would be appreciated.

P.S

I have this included in my `_Layout` page :

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/plugins/jqGrid/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/PageHelpers/jqDateTimePicker.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/plugins/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/plugins/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and  I tried to explicitly include those :

```
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/plugins/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/plugins/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

in my view. So with this set-up it's not working.

Comment: What do you see in the dev tools?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I see - "Valid is not a function"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the jQuery and jQuery Validate plugin scripts on your page.

If you also include the ASP.Net MVC unobtrusive validation script, everything will happen automatically.

**EDIT**: You need to include the unobtrusive validation script *after* jQuery Validate, or the automatic setup won't work.

Comment: Please see the edit of the original post and if possible write what exactly I have to include (or exclude if something is not needed)

Comment: @Leron: Now what do you see in the dev tools?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submitDocument').click(function () {
        window.alert('Hi');
        var test = ($("#Forms").valid()); //Here code modified.
        window.alert('bye');
    })
});
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to change something

Comment: `Forms` is not an ID; it's a controller name

Answer (score 1):

@SLaks is right, include the necessary js files in the head section of the page and use the developer tools included in your browser (IE, Chrome or Safari) to check the js console if something goes wrong.

if you want to use an ID for your form change the opening form command to

@using (Html.BeginForm("RecieveDataFromDocument", "Forms", FormMethod.Post))
{

}

and correct the method valid() to validate()